# Magento saving a custom attribute to customer

Tags: magento

I have added my custom attribute to my customer and it is well displayed on my customer form in back. But when I try to submit it it is triggering an error :

> ```
> magento Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in field list
> ```
>
> This error is triggerd exactly in my CustomerController on $customer->save(); call.
>   I checked in my post and I have those 3 new fields in my posted data

My config is like that :

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                <my_id>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                </my_id>
                <adhesion_date>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                </adhesion_date>
                <favorite_shop_id>
                    <create>1</create>
                    <update>1</update>
                </favorite_shop_id>
            </customer_account>
        </fieldsets>
        <models>
            <Company_Module>
                <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>Company_Module_resource</resourceModel>
            </Company_Module>
            <Company_Module_resource>
                <class>Company_Module_Model_Resource</class>
            </Company_Module_resource>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <Company_Module>
                <class>Company_Module_Block</class>
            </Company_Module>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <Company_Module>
                <class>Company_Module_Helper</class>
            </Company_Module>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <Company_Module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Company_Module</module>
                    <class>Company_Module_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
                <customer_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </customer_write>
                <customer_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </customer_read>
            </Company_Module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

And my creation of attribute which was successful was like that :

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


/**
 * @param $attribute
 * @param $increment
 */
function setAttribute($attribute,$increment){
    $used_in_forms=array();

    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
    $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", $increment)
    ;
    $attribute->save();
}

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "favorite_shop_id",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Favorite shop",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "Company_Module/eav_entity_attribute_source_customerOptions",
    "visible"  => true,
    "global"   => 0, // visible only on store
    "required" => false,
    "default"  => 0,
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"   => false,
    "note"     => "",
    'user_defined' => true

));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "favorite_shop_id");
setAttribute($attribute,201);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "my_id",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Module Id",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => '',
    "visible"  => true,
    "global"   => 0, // visible only on store
    "required" => false,
    "default"  => 0,
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"   => true,
    "note"     => "",
    'user_defined' => true

));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "my_id");
setAttribute($attribute,202);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "adhesion_date",  array(
    "type"     => "date",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Adhesion date",
    "input"    => "date",
    "source"   => '',
    "visible"  => true,
    "global"   => 0, // visible only on store
    "required" => false,
    "default"  => date( Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateStrFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
        strtotime('today')),
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"   => false,
    "note"     => "",
    'user_defined' => true

));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "adhesion_date");
setAttribute($attribute,203);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: what is the code to save the data ?

Comment: I save with app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php and its save method. I havent use any override so it is the  $customer->save() function that is used.